# convert string to blobKey in google app engine python

Tags: google-app-engine

I am trying to convert a **string** to a **blobKey**.

In python, I set `blobKey = 'AMIfv95YT6H488PD6GhOL7xVrqg_juiH3Dh63yrf'`.

But I get the error: `BadValueError: Expected BlobKey, got 'AMIfv95YT6H488PD6GhOL7xVrqg_juiH3Dh63yrf'`

Thanks for any advice!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should be

blobkey = BlobKey('AMIfv95YT6H488PD6GhOL7xVrqg_juiH3Dh63yrf')

The docs say

> You can convert this string to a BlobKey value by passing the string
>   to the BlobKey() constructor.

https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/blobstore/blobkeyclass

Comment: Thanks again Tim. I tried that before, but I just realized I didn't have `from google.appengine.ext.blobstore import BlobKey`